# sed replace a text with text in variable

Tags: linux, bash, sed, scripting

We have a ASCII art like the following

```
ART  _____                            
ART |  __ \               
ART | |__) |__  ___ _ __   
ART |  ___/ _ \/ _ \ '__|  
ART | |  |  __/  __/ |    
ART |_|   \___|\___|_|     
ART                        
ART
```

We have a variable ${art}="123456" and want to replace ART with ${art}, so the system will print the standard output like this

```
123456  _____                            
123456 |  __ \               
123456 | |__) |__  ___ _ __   
123456 |  ___/ _ \/ _ \ '__|  
123456 | |  |  __/  __/ |    
123456 |_|   \___|\___|_|     
123456                        
123456
```

I have tried this as this post suggests

```
sed -i "s/ART/${art}/g" ascii-art
```

The following error message shows up:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated `s' command
```

I am in `Linux ip-10-22-37-149 4.4.8-20.46.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Apr 27 19:28:52 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux (Amazon EC2)`

sed --version returns:

```
GNU sed version 4.2.1
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE,
to the extent permitted by law.

GNU sed home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/>.
General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
E-mail bug reports to: <bug-gnu-utils@gnu.org>.
Be sure to include the word ``sed'' somewhere in the ``Subject:'' field.
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Works fine for me. Try `sed -i"" "s/ART/${art}/g" ascii-art` - note the extra quotes after -i.

Comment: This would happen if the value of `$art` contains a `/` character. But `123456` shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @SiKing There's no difference between `-i` and `-i""`. An empty string is simply removed by the shell.

Comment: works fine for me `sed -i 's/ART/${art}/g' <filename>`

Comment: Add the output from `sed --version` to your post.

Comment: @Barman Not correct. On a Mac, the empty string is required for sed -i.

Comment: @SiKing: Use `tab` to complete usernames. Barmar isn't Barman.

Comment: @chubaka Looks like you are using Amazon linux AMI which is based on Rhel. I am on centos 7 and  following worked `sed -i "s/ART/$art/g" fun_art`. The double quotes preserve bash variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$art` contains `/`, you might need to backslash it or use a different delimiter.

Or, use Perl:

```
perl -i -pe 's/ART/$ENV{art}/g' -- file
```

this will work when `$art` is exported, if it isn't, just export it for the command:

```
art=$art perl ...
```